What is the DDL keyword that creates index in Microsoft SQL Server?
I have a create table SQL statement with the following column:
status_id tinyint not null,

Is there any additional keyword to make it indexed column?

Just indexing that one column is unlikely to be helpful, as you are almost certainly going to want to INCLUDE other columns, no?

@ThomA, I have other columns. I have foreign keys that I know that they are automatically indexed. I also have unique columns that again I know that are automatically indexed. This question is for columns that are neither unique nor foreign keys.

You have to use a separate create index statement, the syntax is something like: Create nonclustered index IX_someName ON tableName (status_id)

You don't "have" to, @siggemannen .

Oh wow, @ThomA, i have to update my internal sql syntax, thanks :D

Foreign keys are not automatically indexed

What was missing from the official documentation that required a question here?

@DaleK, either a DDL keyword that marks a column as index or human friendly documentation.

@DaleK, if you pinpoint a human friendly official documentation. Plus how you have found it using a search engine then I will delete my question.

(Almost if not all) The documentation for SQL Server includes a syntax section, ilhan, so searching "CREATE TABLE SQL SERVER" (at least for me) gives the documentation as the second result (cause w3schools...), and in there you can see the full syntax, which shows how to inline a column index.

In answer to your question; yes, you can inline INDEX a column. The syntax is just like when you inline a CONSTRAINT:
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable (MyID int IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable PRIMARY KEY,
                          MyColumn varchar(30) NOT NULL,
                          MyStatus tinyint NOT NULL INDEX IX_MyTable_MyStatus,
                          MyDate date NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_MyTable_MyDate DEFAULT (SYSDATETIME()));

The only problem with this, however, is that the INDEX is only on MyStatus, so it could easily not be helpful.
Imagine a query like the following:
SELECT MyID,
       MyColumn,
       MyDate
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE MyStatus = 0;

The INDEX IX_MyTable_MyStatus is not going to be useful here. This is because the index includes none of the other columns returned in the SELECT (other than MyID, owing to it being implicitly included as it's the CLUSTERED index). At best, the index could be used to do a seek followed by a key lookup, but those get expensive quickly. It wouldn't be surprising to see a scan against the table (and that is what happens, see the linked fiddle at the end of this answer).
As such you would be much better off defining the INDEX at the end, and adding the appropriate INCLUDE:
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable (MyID int IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
                          MyColumn varchar(30) NOT NULL,
                          MyStatus tinyint NOT NULL,
                          MyDate date NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_MyTable_MyDate DEFAULT (SYSDATETIME()),
                          INDEX IX_MyTable_MyStatus (MyStatus) INCLUDE (MyColumn,MyDate));

db<>fiddle with query plans

Why The INDEX IX_MyTable_MyStatus is not going to be useful, I know that it is not covering, but  isn't it  still useful on the where part ? I am asking because I do not know how SQL Server deals with indexes.

If you check the linked DB Fiddle, @ErgestBasha , which shows the query plan, you'll see that the answer to "isn't it still useful on the where part" is no. SQL Server doesn't even bother doing a seek followed by a key lookup. Indexes on single columns are rarely useful unless you are going to be often doing very narrowly scoped queries, or UNIQUE INDEXes.

For the above example, it's not unless I change the number of rows that have a status of 1 to 1 in ~750 that a key lookup is used, when searching for rows with a value of 1: db<>fiddle. And for a value of 0 obviously a scan is still much better.

The most basic statement is:
create index [some name] on [table name] ([column(s)])
This will create the named index on the table specified for the column(s) listed.  Caution: You don't want too many columns as indexed columns.  If this is for MS SQL Server, then the online help for create index is extensive.
There are a number of "enhancements" you can add, such as CLUSTERED, UNIQUE.
You can specify INCLUDED columns so that the index contains all the data needed for a query (set of queries).

I am aware that there is create index command but it is unnecessary extra command. I mean it looks ugly.

It sounds like your concept of how indexes work is flawed. This idea to have a separate index for each column that might be used in a query predicate is wrong. It is rarely helpful to have an index for just one column by itself.
To help evolve your understanding of indexes, consider a table Person with columns for FirstName, LastName, and Email.
You want to find the email address for John Smith, so you write a query like this:
SELECT Email FROM Person WHERE FirstName = 'John' AND LastName = 'Smith'

But the query is slow. So with your current understanding, you add an index on FirstName and another separate index on LastName, and run the query again.
Now the query is likely somewhat faster... but it's not yet ideal.  One of the indexes was wasted and not used by the query at all. The query above can only check either the FirstName index or the  LastName index. It cannot use both in the same pass through the table. Moreover, the query is going to need to reference back to the table for every result from the index. If it used the LastName index, it must still check back with the original table to see if the FirstName value matches and to retrieve the Email.
This is enough, depending on factors like the size of the table, that the database might even still choose to scan through the table, without using an index at all.
We can do better. Let's take a step forward and build ONE index on the two columns:
LastName, FirstName

Order matters! Based on the selectivity of LastName vs FirstName, you might also choose to reverse the order of those columns. Now we're nearly certain the database will use this index for the query, which will definitely be a lot faster. The query will be able to efficiently find out which rows it needs, and can seek back to the original table for just those rows to the find the Email column.
In the context of the larger application, this index may even be all you need. If you do lots of different kinds of lookups based on name, you may find the overhead cost for maintaining the different kinds of indexes exceeds the benefit.
But for just this query, let's take another step and build the index to use all three columns, like this:
 LastName, FirstName, Email

As before, selectivity matters for the first two columns. The addition of the third column allows the database to satisfy the query from the index alone. We no longer need to seek back to the table at all. This is said to be a covering index.
But there is one final step to take:
 LastName, FirstName INCLUDE Email

Here we use INCLUDE for the Email address to tell the database it does not have to sort Email values within the index. This improves efficiency, because if you change your Email address, to maintain the index now the database only has to change the value in the index; it does NOT have to reposition the row.

"your concept of how indexes work is flawed" my flawled thing here is my experience writing DDL manually for Microsoft SQL Server, that includes a keyword for index. Oterwise I use multi-column index, that you are mentioning, for at least 10 years..
